# 2-adic valuation of a certain binomial sum

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence (of rational numbers) given by
$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}k\frac{k}{n+k}.$$
Let $s(n)$ be the sum of binary digits of $n$, i.e. the total number of $1$'s.

> **QUESTION.** Is it true that the $2$-adic valuation of the denominator of $a_n$ equals $s(n)$?
> It seems so, experimentally.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First we notice that
\begin{split} 
a_n & = n \int_0^1 x^n (1+x)^{n-1}{\rm d}x \\
& = n \int_0^1 (1-x)^n (2-x)^{n-1}{\rm d}x \\
& = n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k}2^k (-1)^{n-1-k} \int_0^1 (1-x)^n x^{n-1-k}{\rm d}x \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k (-1)^{n-1-k} \binom{2n}{k} / \binom{2n}n. \\
\end{split}
Now, the numerator in the last expression is odd, and thus $\nu_2(a_n)=-\nu_2(\tbinom{2n}n)=-s(n)$ by [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem). QED

Comment: I inserted $\binom{n-1}{k}$ in the third line.

Comment: Indeed, thanks!

Comment: Btw, integers $a_n\cdot \binom{2n}{n}$ are listed in [OEIS A240721](https://oeis.org/A240721).

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, I noticed that if we take a common denominator for $a_n$ as coming out of the terms $n+k$ then one would get $\prod_{j=1}^n(n+j)=\frac{(2n)!}{n!}$. Hence, we may rewrite the given sequence as follows:
\begin{align*} \sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}k\frac{k}{n+k}
&=\frac{n!}{(2n)!}\sum_{k=1}^nk\binom{n}k\frac{\prod_{j=1}^n(n+j)}{n+k} \\
&=\binom{2n}n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(n+1)\cdots(n+k-1)}{(k-1)!}\cdot\frac{(n+k+1)\cdots(2n)}{(n-k)!} \\
&=\binom{2n}n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}\binom{2n}{n+k}
\end{align*}
and the numerators (evidently integers) actually agree with what Max Alekseyev's referral to [OEIS A240721](https://oeis.org/A240721). As an aside, we gather the identity that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}\binom{2n}{n+k}=
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}k2^k(-1)^{n-1-k}.$$

Comment: It is not immediately clear from your expression that the numerator is odd, which though becomes obvious from the expression that I derived.

Comment: True. I added this to show connections.